# Wifi drops after a while on Asus laptop with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have Asus Zenbook ux303ub. There was Windows on it and Wifi works perfectly.

After installing Ubuntu (i had: 16.04, 17.04 and, currently, 18.04) there is  a problem with Wifi connection using **some** routers. With my phone as hot-spot it works perfectly.

But then I use my home router wifi drops after a while. Restarting network-manager helps, but after 2-3 minutes it drops again.

I tryed a lot of things, but didn't find a solution.

There's some info, that can be useful (also, i can provide anth other):

```
ilya@ilya-asus:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 48:45:20:83:31:50
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-16-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=172.20.10.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:125 memory:df100000-df101fff

ilya@ilya-asus:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inspect the logs, with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: @waltinator here it is: https://pastebin.com/jhWCEWpq

Comment: I don't see a "drop" in your logvomit.

Comment: @waltinator sorry, what do you mean? This is all input, that I had from this command. By “grep drop” there’s no lines (checked twice).